# Receiveing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when trying to map through questions in new component in quiz app

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to build a quiz app with a quiz-api from online. My mission is to get 10 random questions from the api that has one correct answer and three incorrect ones. After every click there should be a textbox to say whether the code is correct or incorrect. and after 10 questions there should be a counter showing how many of the questions you got correct.

At the moment I have split them into three components.

Component number one fetches the api, and split it down so that you only get one question at a time.

2nd one recieves all the answers both correct and incorrect (and I want these to be randomized as well)

and the third one is the counter that will show the sum of correct answers out of the 10 questions.

The problem I am receiving right now is in the third component that is giving me TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

I honestly have no idea why or how to get past this. I have looked for many questions online that gets the same errors but none of the solutions have worked for me. Can somebody please tell me what the problem is?

I can add all of the components here as they are linked but the error I am receiving is coming from.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const API =
  "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=20&difficulty=medium";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: [
        this.props.correct_answer,
        this.props.incorrect_answers
      ],
      question: "",
      results: [],
      isShowing: false
    };
  }



  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({
      isShowing: true,
      score: this.state.score + 1,
      correct_answer: event.target.value,
      incorrect_answers: event.target.value
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.populateAppWithData();
  }

  populateAppWithData() {
    const showData = fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ results: data.results }));
    console.log(showData);
  }

  render() {

    const results = this.state.results.slice().map((result, index) => (
      <ul onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} key={`result ${index}`}>
        <li>
          <h2> {result.question}</h2>
          {""}
          <h5>{result.correct_answer}</h5>
        </li>
        {result.incorrect_answers.map(incAnswer => (
          <li>
            <h5>{incAnswer}</h5>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    ));

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Quiz App</h1>
        <div>{results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)]}</div>
        <div>Score: {this.state.score}</div>
        {this.state.isShowing && (
          <Counter
            className="modal"
            show={this.state.isShowing}
            question={this.state.question}
            correct_answer={this.state.correct_answer}
          />
        )}
        <Counter questions={this.state.question}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class TheAnswers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      correct_answer: "",
      answered: undefined, isRight: undefined
    };
  }
  answerClicked(answer) {
    const { hasAnswered, correct_answer } = this.props;
    return event => {
      if (this.state.answered) return;
      const isRight = correct_answer === answer;
      hasAnswered(isRight);
      this.setState({ answered: answer, isRight });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { question, correct_answer, incorrect_answers } = this.props;
    const { answered, isRight } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>{question}
        {[...incorrect_answers, correct_answer]
          .map(answer => <div onClick={this.answerClicked(answer)}>{answer} </div>)}
        {answered && `You answered ${answered}`}
        {answered && isRight && "This is correct!"}
        {answered && !isRight && "This is incorrect. please try again"}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      right: 0,
      counter: 0,
    };

  }
  questionAnswered(isRight) {
    this.setState(({ counter, right }) => ({ counter: counter + 1, right: right + isRight }));
  }

  render() {
    const { question } = this.props;
    const { counter, right } = this.state;
    const unanswered = this.props.question - counter;
    if (unanswered <= 0) {
      return `All answered`;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        You have {unanswered} questions left, {right} are already correct!
      {question.map(it => <TheAnswers key={it.question} {...it}
          hasAnswered={it => this.questionAnswered(it)} />)}
        <div>{this.state.counter}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Your `App` component's state doesn't seem to have a `question` property, you're using that to pass as a property to `Counter`

Comment: Also, you're using both `question` and `questions` as properties for `Counter`.

Comment: @Titus I just noticed that. Thanks I made the changes accordingly but I am still receiving the same type of error

Comment: Can you edit the question to reflect the changes that you've made ?

Comment: @Titus I just edited it. The property in the api was question all along not questions.

Comment: Even though you've set `question: ""` in your state (which is not an array) you still have `<Counter questions={this.state.question}/>` (`questions` with an `s` at the end instead of `question`) which means that for that component, `this.prop.question` will be `undefined`.

Comment: @Titus how silly of me. Thank you so much!! it's all working now. Gotta try to figure out the rest of the code now. Many thanks!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help, good luck.